# Active Admin Nested models not populating in edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

So, I've been tinkering around with Active Admin, and so far even though the documentation is not great I've been sailing along. But I encountered an issue when I try to edit a model with a few belongs_to associations. The form does not populate with the records on those associations ... and since Active Admin does a lot of things by magic, I'm at a loss of what the issue could be because as I said, the documentation is somewhat lacking for Active Admin and as far as my searches went, no one had a similar issue ... so, I'm open to ideas.

I get the records for all the Couple attributes but for Wedding, Bride & Groom nothing

***models/couple.rb***

```
class Couple < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :set_full_name
 belongs_to :wedding, :dependent => :destroy
 belongs_to :groom, :class_name => "Partner::Groom", :dependent => :destroy
 belongs_to :bride, :class_name => "Partner::Bride", :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :groom, :bride, :wedding
 attr_accessible :bride, :groom, :bride_id, :groom_id, :notification_email, :contact_address,     :comment,:bride_attributes, :groom_attributes, :wedding_attributes
 validates :notification_email, email: true, uniqueness: true, presence: true
 validates :contact_address, presence: true
 validates :wedding, :groom, :bride, presence: true
end
```

***admin/couples.rb***

```
ActiveAdmin.register Couple do
  menu :priority => 3, url: ->{ admin_couples_path(locale: I18n.locale) }, :label => proc{I18n.t('general.couples')}

  scope proc{I18n.t('admin.couples.scope.all')},:all, :default => true
  scope proc{I18n.t('admin.couples.scope.past_week')},:past_week do |couples|
    couples.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', Time.now - 1.week, Time.now)
  end
  scope proc{I18n.t('admin.couples.scope.last_month')},:last_month do |couples|
    couples.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', Time.now - 1.month, Time.now)
  end

  form do |c|
   c.inputs "Couples" do
       c.input :contact_address, :label => t('admin.couples.attributes.contact_address')
       c.input :notification_email, :label => t('admin.couples.attributes.notification_email')
       c.input :comment, :label => t('admin.couples.attributes.comment')
   end
   c.inputs "Groom" do
     c.inputs :for => :groom_attributes do |g|
       g.input :first_name, :label => t('general.first_name')
       g.input :last_name, :label => t('general.last_name')
       g.input :email, :label => t('general.email')
       g.input :date_of_birth, as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year - 10, end_year: Date.today.year - 80, :label => t('general.date_of_birth')
       g.input :dni
       g.input :mobile_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.mobile_number')
       g.input :phone_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.phone_number')
       g.input :facebook
       g.input :twitter
     end
   end
   c.inputs "Bride" do
     c.inputs :for => :bride_attributes do |b|
       b.input :first_name, :label => t('general.first_name')
       b.input :last_name, :label => t('general.last_name')
       b.input :email, as: :email, :label => t('general.email')
       b.input :date_of_birth, :label => t('general.date_of_birth'), as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year - 10, end_year: Date.today.year - 80
       b.input :dni
       b.input :mobile_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.mobile_number')
       b.input :phone_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.phone_number')
       b.input :facebook
       b.input :twitter
     end
   end

    c.inputs "Wedding" do
      c.inputs :for => :wedding_attributes do |w|
        w.input :date, as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 10,:label => t('admin.weddings.date')
        w.input :ceremony_time, as: :time_select, :label => t('admin.weddings.ceremony_time')
        w.input :ceremony_place, :label => t('admin.weddings.ceremony_place')
        w.input :civil_ceremony_date, as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 10, :label => t('admin.weddings.civil_ceremony_date')
        w.input :civil_ceremony_time, as: :time_select, :label => t('admin.weddings.civil_ceremony_time')
        w.input :civil_ceremony_place, :label => t('admin.weddings.civil_ceremony_place')
        w.input :facebook_notifications_enabled, as: :boolean
        w.input :twitter_notifications_enabled, as: :boolean
        w.input :number_of_guests, :label => t('admin.weddings.number_of_guests')
        w.input :site_id, as: :select, :collection => Site.all.map{|u| ["#{u.country}", u.id]}
      end
    end
    c.actions
  end

  index do |c|
    c.column :id
    c.column t('admin.couples.full_name'), :full_name,:sortable => :full_name  do |couple|
      couple.full_name
    end
    c.column t('admin.couples.attributes.notification_email'),:notification_email
    c.column t('admin.couples.attributes.contact_address'),:contact_address
    c.default_actions
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I found out what the issue was ... and since I fixed it, I want to leave what I found out here, so if anyone else is faced with the same issue, they have an answer.

Apparently I was building the form wrong for the nested models, instead of

```
c.inputs :for => :groom_attributes do |g|
```

I used

```
c.inputs for: [:groom, c.object.groom || c.object.build_groom] do |g|
```

***admin/couples.rb***

```
ActiveAdmin.register Couple do
  menu :priority => 3, url: ->{ admin_couples_path(locale: I18n.locale) }, :label => proc{I18n.t('general.couples')}

  scope proc{I18n.t('admin.couples.scope.all')},:all, :default => true
  scope proc{I18n.t('admin.couples.scope.past_week')},:past_week do |couples|
    couples.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', Time.now - 1.week, Time.now)
  end
  scope proc{I18n.t('admin.couples.scope.last_month')},:last_month do |couples|
    couples.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', Time.now - 1.month, Time.now)
  end

  form do |c|
    c.semantic_errors *c.object.errors.keys
   c.inputs "Couples" do
       c.input :contact_address, :label => t('admin.couples.attributes.contact_address')
       c.input :notification_email, :label => t('admin.couples.attributes.notification_email')
       c.input :comment, :label => t('admin.couples.attributes.comment')
   end
   c.inputs "Groom" do
     c.inputs for: [:groom, c.object.groom || c.object.build_groom] do |g|
       g.input :first_name, :label => t('general.first_name')
       g.input :last_name, :label => t('general.last_name')
       g.input :email, :label => t('general.email')
       g.input :date_of_birth, as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year - 10, end_year: Date.today.year - 80, :label => t('general.date_of_birth')
       g.input :dni
       g.input :mobile_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.mobile_number')
       g.input :phone_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.phone_number')
       g.input :facebook
       g.input :twitter
     end
   end
   c.inputs "Bride" do
     c.inputs for: [:bride, c.object.bride || c.object.build_bride] do |b|
       b.input :first_name, :label => t('general.first_name')
       b.input :last_name, :label => t('general.last_name')
       b.input :email, as: :email, :label => t('general.email')
       b.input :date_of_birth, :label => t('general.date_of_birth'), as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year - 10, end_year: Date.today.year - 80
       b.input :dni
       b.input :mobile_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.mobile_number')
       b.input :phone_number, as: :phone, :label => t('general.phone_number')
       b.input :facebook
       b.input :twitter
     end
   end

    c.inputs "Wedding" do
      c.inputs for: [:wedding, c.object.wedding || c.object.build_wedding] do |w|
        w.input :date, as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 10,:label => t('admin.weddings.date')
        w.input :ceremony_time, as: :time_select, :label => t('admin.weddings.ceremony_time')
        w.input :ceremony_place, :label => t('admin.weddings.ceremony_place')
        w.input :civil_ceremony_date, as: :date_select, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 10, :label => t('admin.weddings.civil_ceremony_date')
        w.input :civil_ceremony_time, as: :time_select, :label => t('admin.weddings.civil_ceremony_time')
        w.input :civil_ceremony_place, :label => t('admin.weddings.civil_ceremony_place')
        w.input :facebook_notifications_enabled, as: :boolean
        w.input :twitter_notifications_enabled, as: :boolean
        w.input :number_of_guests, :label => t('admin.weddings.number_of_guests')
        w.input :site_id, as: :select, :collection => Site.all.map{|u| ["#{u.country}", u.id]}
      end
    end
    c.actions
  end

  index do |c|
    c.column :id
    c.column t('admin.couples.full_name'), :full_name,:sortable => :full_name  do |couple|
      couple.full_name
    end
    c.column t('admin.couples.attributes.notification_email'),:notification_email
    c.column t('admin.couples.attributes.contact_address'),:contact_address
    c.default_actions
  end
 #
end
```